# Use Regex To Extract Line Of Text Excluding Lines With Certain Phrases

Tags: regex, vb.net, regex-lookarounds

I have a problem I've been struggling with for the past couple of hours. I couldn't figure it out even after looking at similar posts on stackoverflow and researching so I'm just going to post it here and I'm sure someone can figure it out in two seconds...

Here is the sample text:

```
 1) IF045196B LOREM-IPSEM,DOLOR1          G35311          12/07/2018  09/07/1985   FNL  91452SB=;*      TRANS TO HOLD ORDER
 2) IF045197B LOREM-IPSEM,DOLOR1          G35311          12/07/2018  09/07/1985   FNL  91377SB=;*      ALTERNATE LAB DRAW
 3) IF044770B LOREM-IPSEM,DOLOR1          G35311          09/26/2018  09/07/1985        3020SBX=;R      RANDOM TEXT
  RANDOM TEXT;*    LOREM IPSEM
 4) IF044445B LOREM-IPSEM,DOLOR16         G35311          07/18/2018  09/07/1985        3020SBX=;R      RANDOM TEXT
  RANDOM TEXT;*    LOREM IPSEM
 5) IF044446B LOREM-IPSEM,DOLOR17         G35311          07/18/2018  09/07/1985        10165SB=;S/R    MOVIE TITLE
  3020SBX=;R    RANDOM TEXT         RANDOM TEXT;*    LOREM IPSEM
 6) IF044447B LOREM-IPSEM,DOLOR18         G35311          07/18/2018  09/07/1985        10256SB=;S/R    MOVIE TITLE
  3020SBX=;R    RANDOM TEXT         RANDOM TEXT;*    LOREM IPSEM
 7) IF044449B LOREM-IPSEM,DOLOR19         G35311          07/18/2018  09/07/1985        10256SB=;S/R    MOVIE TITLE
  3020SBX=;R    RANDOM TEXT         RANDOM TEXT;*    LOREM IPSEM
```

Lines 1 and 2 are not matches because they say "TRANSFER TO HOLD ORDER" and "ALTERNATE LAB DRAW".

I need a Regular Expression that will return lines 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7 back to me. I need the entire line back and then I am going to manipulate those strings later in my program.

So just to be clear, I should receive 5 matches back.

```
3) IF044770B LOREM-IPSEM,DOLOR1          G35311          09/26/2018  09/07/1985        3020SBX=;R      RANDOM TEXTRANDOM TEXT;*    LOREM IPSEM
4) IF044445B LOREM-IPSEM,DOLOR16         G35311          07/18/2018  09/07/1985        3020SBX=;R      RANDOM TEXTRANDOM TEXT;*    LOREM IPSEM
5) IF044446B LOREM-IPSEM,DOLOR17         G35311          07/18/2018  09/07/1985        10165SB=;S/R    MOVIE TITLE 3020SBX=;R    RANDOM TEXT         RANDOM TEXT;*    LOREM IPSEM
6) IF044447B LOREM-IPSEM,DOLOR18         G35311          07/18/2018  09/07/1985        10256SB=;S/R    MOVIE TITLE 3020SBX=;R    RANDOM TEXT         RANDOM TEXT;*    LOREM IPSEM
7) IF044449B LOREM-IPSEM,DOLOR19         G35311          07/18/2018  09/07/1985        10256SB=;S/R    MOVIE TITLE 3020SBX=;R    RANDOM TEXT         RANDOM TEXT;*    LOREM IPSEM
```

I think the answer is going to involve some sort of negative look ahead/behind in combination with the below regex.

```
(?<=\s+\d+\)\s+).*
```

Here's the permalink if you want to test it out. [Regex Permalink](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5Cs%2B%5Cd%2B%5C%29%5Cs%2B%29.*&i=%201%29%20IF045196B%20LOREM-IPSEM%2CDOLOR1%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20G35311%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2012%2F07%2F2018%20%2009%2F07%2F1985%20%20%20FNL%20%2091452SB%3D%3B*%20%20%20%20%20%20TRANS%20TO%20HOLD%20ORDER%0D%0A2%29%20IF045197B%20LOREM-IPSEM%2CDOLOR1%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20G35311%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2012%2F07%2F2018%20%2009%2F07%2F1985%20%20%20FNL%20%2091377SB%3D%3B*%20%20%20%20%20%20ALTERNATE%20LAB%20DRAW%0D%0A3%29%20IF044770B%20LOREM-IPSEM%2CDOLOR1%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20G35311%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2009%2F26%2F2018%20%2009%2F07%2F1985%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%203020SBX%3D%3BR%20%20%20%20%20%20RANDOM%20TEXT%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20RANDOM%20TEXT%3B*%20%20%20%20LOREM%20IPSEM%0D%0A4%29%20IF044445B%20LOREM-IPSEM%2CDOLOR16%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20G35311%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2007%2F18%2F2018%20%2009%2F07%2F1985%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%203020SBX%3D%3BR%20%20%20%20%20%20RANDOM%20TEXT%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20RANDOM%20TEXT%3B*%20%20%20%20LOREM%20IPSEM%0D%0A5%29%20IF044446B%20LOREM-IPSEM%2CDOLOR17%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20G35311%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2007%2F18%2F2018%20%2009%2F07%2F1985%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2010165SB%3D%3BS%2FR%20%20%20%20MOVIE%20TITLE%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%203020SBX%3D%3BR%20%20%20%20RANDOM%20TEXT%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20RANDOM%20TEXT%3B*%20%20%20%20LOREM%20IPSEM%0D%0A6%29%20IF044447B%20LOREM-IPSEM%2CDOLOR18%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20G35311%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2007%2F18%2F2018%20%2009%2F07%2F1985%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2010256SB%3D%3BS%2FR%20%20%20%20MOVIE%20TITLE%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%203020SBX%3D%3BR%20%20%20%20RANDOM%20TEXT%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20RANDOM%20TEXT%3B*%20%20%20%20LOREM%20IPSEM%0D%0A7%29%20IF044449B%20LOREM-IPSEM%2CDOLOR19%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20G35311%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2007%2F18%2F2018%20%2009%2F07%2F1985%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2010256SB%3D%3BS%2FR%20%20%20%20MOVIE%20TITLE%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%203020SBX%3D%3BR%20%20%20%20RANDOM%20TEXT%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20RANDOM%20TEXT%3B*%20%20%20%20LOREM%20IPSEM).

This regex matches the entire line excluding the number at the beginning such as "1)" or "2)". Now I just need the regex to do a negative look ahead and exclude lines 1 and 2 since they have "TRANSFER TO HOLD ORDER" and "ALTERNATE LAB DRAW" in them.

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you,

Mark S.

Comment: If you need to just skip first two lines, there's no need for Regex at all. Do you load this text from a file?

Comment: It's not always just the first two lines. It could be any line.

Comment: Do you load it from file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead to assert that the string does not end with TRANS TO HOLD ORDER or ALTERNATE LAB DRAW.

```
^(?!.*(?:TRANS TO HOLD ORDER|ALTERNATE LAB DRAW)).*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Assert the start of the string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead that will check wat is on the right should not

  - `.*` Match any character 0+ times
  - `(?:TRANS TO HOLD ORDER|ALTERNATE LAB DRAW)` Alternation which will match either of the options and assert the end of the string
- `)` Close negative lookahead.
- `.*$` Match 0+ characters and assert the end of the string

See the [Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f!.*%28%3f%3aTRANS+TO+HOLD+ORDER%7cALTERNATE+LAB+DRAW%29%29.*%24&i=1%29+IF045196B+LOREM-IPSEM%2cDOLOR1++++++++++G35311++++++++++12%2f07%2f2018++09%2f07%2f1985+++FNL++91452SB%3d%3b*++++++TRANS+TO+HOLD+ORDER%0d%0a2%29+IF045197B+LOREM-IPSEM%2cDOLOR1++++++++++G35311++++++++++12%2f07%2f2018++09%2f07%2f1985+++FNL++91377SB%3d%3b*++++++ALTERNATE+LAB+DRAW%0d%0a3%29+IF044770B+LOREM-IPSEM%2cDOLOR1++++++++++G35311++++++++++09%2f26%2f2018++09%2f07%2f1985++++++++3020SBX%3d%3bR++++++RANDOM+TEXT%0d%0a++RANDOM+TEXT%3b*++++LOREM+IPSEM%0d%0a4%29+IF044445B+LOREM-IPSEM%2cDOLOR16+++++++++G35311++++++++++07%2f18%2f2018++09%2f07%2f1985++++++++3020SBX%3d%3bR++++++RANDOM+TEXT%0d%0a++RANDOM+TEXT%3b*++++LOREM+IPSEM%0d%0a5%29+IF044446B+LOREM-IPSEM%2cDOLOR17+++++++++G35311++++++++++07%2f18%2f2018++09%2f07%2f1985++++++++10165SB%3d%3bS%2fR++++MOVIE+TITLE%0d%0a++3020SBX%3d%3bR++++RANDOM+TEXT+++++++++RANDOM+TEXT%3b*++++LOREM+IPSEM%0d%0a6%29+IF044447B+LOREM-IPSEM%2cDOLOR18+++++++++G35311++++++++++07%2f18%2f2018++09%2f07%2f1985++++++++10256SB%3d%3bS%2fR++++MOVIE+TITLE%0d%0a++3020SBX%3d%3bR++++RANDOM+TEXT+++++++++RANDOM+TEXT%3b*++++LOREM+IPSEM%0d%0a7%29+IF044449B+LOREM-IPSEM%2cDOLOR19+++++++++G35311++++++++++07%2f18%2f2018++09%2f07%2f1985++++++++10256SB%3d%3bS%2fR++++MOVIE+TITLE%0d%0a++3020SBX%3d%3bR++++RANDOM+TEXT+++++++++RANDOM+TEXT%3b*++++LOREM+IPSEM&o=m)

Note: 
If the value can be TRANS or TRANSFER, you could use `TRANS(?:FER)?` with an optional part to match FER.

If the text should not be in the string, you could test this [demo vb.net](https://ideone.com/oJl56x). If the text should not be at the end of the string, you could test this [demo](https://ideone.com/NSKPJ5)

If you only need 5 matches, you could match 1+ digits and a closing parenthesis `\d+\)` at the beginning:

`^\d+\)(?!.*(?:TRANS TO HOLD ORDER|ALTERNATE LAB DRAW)).*$`

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cd%2b%5c%29%28%3f!.*%28%3f%3aTRANS+TO+HOLD+ORDER%7cALTERNATE+LAB+DRAW%29%29.*%24&i=1%29+IF045196B+LOREM-IPSEM%2cDOLOR1++++++++++G35311++++++++++12%2f07%2f2018++09%2f07%2f1985+++FNL++91452SB%3d%3b*++++++TRANS+TO+HOLD+ORDER%0d%0a2%29+IF045197B+LOREM-IPSEM%2cDOLOR1++++++++++G35311++++++++++12%2f07%2f2018++09%2f07%2f1985+++FNL++91377SB%3d%3b*++++++ALTERNATE+LAB+DRAW%0d%0a3%29+IF044770B+LOREM-IPSEM%2cDOLOR1++++++++++G35311++++++++++09%2f26%2f2018++09%2f07%2f1985++++++++3020SBX%3d%3bR++++++RANDOM+TEXT%0d%0a++RANDOM+TEXT%3b*++++LOREM+IPSEM%0d%0a4%29+IF044445B+LOREM-IPSEM%2cDOLOR16+++++++++G35311++++++++++07%2f18%2f2018++09%2f07%2f1985++++++++3020SBX%3d%3bR++++++RANDOM+TEXT%0d%0a++RANDOM+TEXT%3b*++++LOREM+IPSEM%0d%0a5%29+IF044446B+LOREM-IPSEM%2cDOLOR17+++++++++G35311++++++++++07%2f18%2f2018++09%2f07%2f1985++++++++10165SB%3d%3bS%2fR++++MOVIE+TITLE%0d%0a++3020SBX%3d%3bR++++RANDOM+TEXT+++++++++RANDOM+TEXT%3b*++++LOREM+IPSEM%0d%0a6%29+IF044447B+LOREM-IPSEM%2cDOLOR18+++++++++G35311++++++++++07%2f18%2f2018++09%2f07%2f1985++++++++10256SB%3d%3bS%2fR++++MOVIE+TITLE%0d%0a++3020SBX%3d%3bR++++RANDOM+TEXT+++++++++RANDOM+TEXT%3b*++++LOREM+IPSEM%0d%0a7%29+IF044449B+LOREM-IPSEM%2cDOLOR19+++++++++G35311++++++++++07%2f18%2f2018++09%2f07%2f1985++++++++10256SB%3d%3bS%2fR++++MOVIE+TITLE%0d%0a++3020SBX%3d%3bR++++RANDOM+TEXT+++++++++RANDOM+TEXT%3b*++++LOREM+IPSEM&o=m)

Edit:

If you have 1 string, you could use a tempered dot approach with a positive lookahead:

`\d+\)(?:(?!TRANS TO HOLD ORDER|ALTERNATE LAB DRAW).)*?(?=\d+\) |$)` [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cd%2b%5c%29%28%3f%3a%28%3f!TRANS+TO+HOLD+ORDER%7cALTERNATE+LAB+DRAW%29.%29*%3f%28%3f%3d%5cd%2b%5c%29+%7c%24%29&i=1%29+IF045196B+LOREM-IPSEM%2cDOLOR1+G35311+12%2f07%2f2018+09%2f07%2f1985+FNL+91452SB%3d%3b*+TRANS+TO+HOLD+ORDER+2%29+IF045197B+LOREM-IPSEM%2cDOLOR1+G35311+12%2f07%2f2018+09%2f07%2f1985+FNL+91377SB%3d%3b*+ALTERNATE+LAB+DRAW+3%29+IF044770B+LOREM-IPSEM%2cDOLOR1+G35311+09%2f26%2f2018+09%2f07%2f1985+3020SBX%3d%3bR+RANDOM+TEXT+RANDOM+TEXT%3b*+LOREM+IPSEM+4%29+IF044445B+LOREM-IPSEM%2cDOLOR16+G35311+07%2f18%2f2018+09%2f07%2f1985+3020SBX%3d%3bR+RANDOM+TEXT+RANDOM+TEXT%3b*+LOREM+IPSEM1%29+IF045196B+LOREM-IPSEM%2cDOLOR1+G35311+12%2f07%2f2018+09%2f07%2f1985+FNL+91452SB%3d%3b*+TRANS+TO+HOLD+ORDER+5%29+IF044446B+LOREM-IPSEM%2cDOLOR17+G35311+07%2f18%2f2018+09%2f07%2f1985+10165SB%3d%3bS%2fR+MOVIE+TITLE+3020SBX%3d%3bR+RANDOM+TEXT+RANDOM+TEXT%3b*+LOREM+IPSEM+6%29+IF044447B+LOREM-IPSEM%2cDOLOR18+G35311+07%2f18%2f2018+09%2f07%2f1985+10256SB%3d%3bS%2fR+MOVIE+TITLE+3020SBX%3d%3bR+RANDOM+TEXT+RANDOM+TEXT%3b*+LOREM+IPSEM+7%29+IF044449B+LOREM-IPSEM%2cDOLOR19+G35311+07%2f18%2f2018+09%2f07%2f1985+10256SB%3d%3bS%2fR+MOVIE+TITLE+3020SBX%3d%3bR+RANDOM+TEXT+RANDOM+TEXT%3b*+LOREM+IPSEM)

Comment: This looks to me like it is the answer. The only thing is that this works on regex101.com but it is not working on regexstorm.net/tester. I will test it out in code at work on Monday and see if it works. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Any chance you could try plugging this into RegexStorm.net/Tester and tell me why it's not working on that website?

Comment: @MarkS I have updated my answer and added a link to regexstorm and a demo.

Comment: Marking this one as the answer. \d+\)(?:(?!TRANS TO HOLD ORDER|ALTERNATE LAB DRAW).)*?(?=\d+\) |$) is the one that works for me. Keep reading below to see how I use it in VB.NET code. Thank you!

Comment: Note to my comment above. \d+)(?:(?!TRANS TO HOLD ORDER|ALTERNATE LAB DRAW).)*?(?=\d+) |$) will only work with the "MultiLine" option enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You're right - you need to use a negative lookahead:

```
^((?!TRANSFER TO HOLD ORDER|ALTERNATE LAB DRAW).)*$
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your help but something is not jiving with VB.Net with both of the above answers.

Answer (score 0):

Update! @The Fourth Bird has provided the correct answer. The correct answer is...

```
\d+\)(?:(?!TRANS TO HOLD ORDER|ALTERNATE LAB DRAW).)*?(?=\d+\) |$)
```

You can see it in an online regex editor here`
 [Online Regex Editor Example](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cd%2B%5C%29%28%3F%3A%28%3F!TRANS%20TO%20HOLD%20ORDER%7CALTERNATE%20LAB%20DRAW%29.%29*%3F%28%3F%3D%5Cd%2B%5C%29%20%7C%24%29&i=%201%29%20IF045196B%20LOREM-IPSEM%2CDOLOR1%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20G35311%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2012%2F07%2F2018%20%2009%2F07%2F1985%20%20%20FNL%20%2091452SB%3D%3B*%20%20%20%20%20%20TRANS%20TO%20HOLD%20ORDER%0D%0A%202%29%20IF045197B%20LOREM-IPSEM%2CDOLOR1%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20G35311%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2012%2F07%2F2018%20%2009%2F07%2F1985%20%20%20FNL%20%2091377SB%3D%3B*%20%20%20%20%20%20ALTERNATE%20LAB%20DRAW%0D%0A%203%29%20IF044770B%20LOREM-IPSEM%2CDOLOR1%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20G35311%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2009%2F26%2F2018%20%2009%2F07%2F1985%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%203020SBX%3D%3BR%20%20%20%20%20%20RANDOM%20TEXT%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20RANDOM%20TEXT%3B*%20%20%20%20LOREM%20IPSEM%0D%0A%204%29%20IF044445B%20LOREM-IPSEM%2CDOLOR16%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20G35311%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2007%2F18%2F2018%20%2009%2F07%2F1985%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%203020SBX%3D%3BR%20%20%20%20%20%20RANDOM%20TEXT%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20RANDOM%20TEXT%3B*%20%20%20%20LOREM%20IPSEM%0D%0A%205%29%20IF044446B%20LOREM-IPSEM%2CDOLOR17%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20G35311%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2007%2F18%2F2018%20%2009%2F07%2F1985%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2010165SB%3D%3BS%2FR%20%20%20%20MOVIE%20TITLE%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%203020SBX%3D%3BR%20%20%20%20RANDOM%20TEXT%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20RANDOM%20TEXT%3B*%20%20%20%20LOREM%20IPSEM%0D%0A%206%29%20IF044447B%20LOREM-IPSEM%2CDOLOR18%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20G35311%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2007%2F18%2F2018%20%2009%2F07%2F1985%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2010256SB%3D%3BS%2FR%20%20%20%20MOVIE%20TITLE%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%203020SBX%3D%3BR%20%20%20%20RANDOM%20TEXT%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20RANDOM%20TEXT%3B*%20%20%20%20LOREM%20IPSEM%0D%0A%207%29%20IF044449B%20LOREM-IPSEM%2CDOLOR19%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20G35311%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2007%2F18%2F2018%20%2009%2F07%2F1985%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2010256SB%3D%3BS%2FR%20%20%20%20MOVIE%20TITLE%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%203020SBX%3D%3BR%20%20%20%20RANDOM%20TEXT%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20RANDOM%20TEXT%3B*%20%20%20%20LOREM%20IPSEM&o=m)

And then to complete out this post, I'm pasting the VB.NET code that goes along with it. Copy and paste the code right into Visual Studio to try it yourself.

A special thank you to @The Fourth Bird. Phenominal work, thank you!

Please rate this post up if it helps you.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Program
Sub Main(args As String())

    Dim RegexStringPattern As String = "(?<=\s+\d+\)\s+).*"
    Dim StringToSearch As String = " 1) IF045196B LOREM-IPSEM,DOLOR1          G35311          12/07/2018  09/07/1985   FNL  91452SB=;*      TRANS TO HOLD ORDER
                                    2) IF045197B LOREM-IPSEM,DOLOR1          G35311          12/07/2018  09/07/1985   FNL  91377SB=;*      ALTERNATE LAB DRAW
                                    3) IF044770B LOREM-IPSEM,DOLOR1          G35311          09/26/2018  09/07/1985        3020SBX=;R      RANDOM TEXT
                                    RANDOM TEXT;*    LOREM IPSEM
                                    4) IF044445B LOREM-IPSEM,DOLOR16         G35311          07/18/2018  09/07/1985        3020SBX=;R      RANDOM TEXT
                                    RANDOM TEXT;*    LOREM IPSEM
                                    5) IF044446B LOREM-IPSEM,DOLOR17         G35311          07/18/2018  09/07/1985        10165SB=;S/R    MOVIE TITLE
                                    3020SBX=;R    RANDOM TEXT         RANDOM TEXT;*    LOREM IPSEM
                                    6) IF044447B LOREM-IPSEM,DOLOR18         G35311          07/18/2018  09/07/1985        10256SB=;S/R    MOVIE TITLE
                                    3020SBX=;R    RANDOM TEXT         RANDOM TEXT;*    LOREM IPSEM
                                    7) IF044449B LOREM-IPSEM,DOLOR19         G35311          07/18/2018  09/07/1985        10256SB=;S/R    MOVIE TITLE
                                    3020SBX=;R    RANDOM TEXT         RANDOM TEXT;*    LOREM IPSEM"

    Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(StringToSearch, RegexStringPattern)
    Dim listOfStrings As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    Dim listOfCorrectStrings As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

    For Each match As Match In matches
        For Each capture As Capture In match.Captures
            Console.WriteLine(capture.Value)
            listOfStrings.Add(capture.Value)
        Next
    Next

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: If you have a whole string, try it like this `\d+\)(?:(?!TRANS TO HOLD ORDER|ALTERNATE LAB DRAW).)*?(?=\d+\) |$)` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/8Vfqpx/1)

Comment: Thank you, I tried this one and it's not working. It's hard to explain but it is a whole string like in the code above and there is a space before the number. So the start of line one for example is " 1)" without the quotes.

Comment: Yes! This is the correct answer. I plugged it into the code and it worked. I had to turn on the multiline option which is why it wasn't working on RegexStorm.Net